# Autostart OpenVPN Client in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, openvpn

I'm currently using Network Connections manager to manually make an OpenVPN connection from a Lubuntu client machine to an OpenVPN server.

Is there a way to automatically make the client connection during startup when Lubuntu boots? I can't find a working solution online.

The `client.conf` file is currently in `/etc/openvpn`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/default/openvpn` in you favourite text editor, and then change `AUTOSTART` to  `AUTOSTART=all`

Comment: I uncommented Autostart="all" and restarted openvpn and network-manager, but didn't seem to work. Do I need the client key and cert files in `/etc/openvpn` directory? Or should the client.conf be in `/etc/default/openvpn`? I think I'm missing a piece. Currently the keys an cert files are in the Documents folder and are linked to them in Network Connections. Thanks!

Comment: yes the client.conf must be moved there

Comment: hmmm moving client.conf from `/etc/openvpn` to `/etc/default` didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo update-rc.d openvpn enable` ?

Comment: Tried that and unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was quite simple, but didn't notice before. You have to select Automatically Connect to VPN in Network Connections. The reason I didn't see this before is because this setting is found **in the Main/Wired connection**, not under your VPN settings in Network Connections.

Tick that box, and it connects on startup.

Comment: This should be the recommended answer for all questions of this type.